# Read Hikvision camera on PC over RS485

Tags: serial, rs485, camera

I have a Hikvision IP camera. I can login onto the camera and stream live video through hikvision website.
However, the connection of the ip camera to the PC is via ethernet, which is limited to only 100m. I want to extend the cable to 300m due to which I must use RS485 connection. (I've tried FathomX, it works but for some reason I cannot use that).

Is there a way through which I can stream live video of the IP camera on PC over RS485 connection between the camera and the PC?

Comment: No, unless the manual says so. But basically this is how to use an electrical product question. Or how to extend Ethernet to 300m question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run the video over RS485. The RS485 connection on those cameras is specifically for control and alarms. There are sometimes also separate connections for audio and composite video out, but those are unlikely to work over 300m.

Your best option would probably be to run 300m of OM2 or OM3 multimode fibre instead, then use a 1000BASE-T to 1000BASE-SX media converter on the camera side, and either another media converter or a cheap switch with an SFP module on the other end.